# AdMob custom events for ADs mediation on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am doing ADs mediation through AdMob, and my goal is to automatically determine the eCPM, and select the best ADs network to pull ADs from.

However, it seems the AD network I am using (FB / MoPub) can not directly be configured to attain that goal, so I'll need to use the custom events

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/custom-events#notify_admob_mediation

But I really don't understand the sample code provided on their website...

It even contains a type called: **SampleBanner**, and I really don't get it!

Have anyone done this before?

It'd be a big help if anyone can provide a more detailed illustration as to how to implement the custom events for AdMob in Swift

Answer (score 1):

I can't give detailed recommendations about implementing events in swift, but my guess is that sample code differs, because it's made for test mode to avoid manual customization in order to prevent better results from other networks. I mean AdMom thinks about itself first of all))) But what you're trying to do is called programmatic mediation and it's definitely the right way to spreading traffic. I also thought about it, but i'm not that technically skilled to implement it myself. I checked that thread on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/iosdev/comments/41qie7/best_app_monetization_ad_network_solution/  and I think this might be helpful for you as well, cause if you're using fb,mopub and admob, getting access to other "competitors" would provide better results. I'm using appodeal for now and it really provides around 20% more revenue from admob alone. The point is that they "automatically determine the eCPM, and select the best ADs network to pull ADs from". hope this can be useful

Comment: thanks you for the suggestion :) but it does not really solve my problems. thank you anyway